# вывести столбец матрицы numpy python

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть матрица   5×6 из целых чисел на интервале [0,50]. Пытаюсь вывести  столбец с содержащий максимальное значение во всей матрице.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,50,(5,6))
condition  = arr.max()
```

Как вывести столбец с максимальным элементом средствами `numpy` Python ?

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```
In [51]: arr
Out[51]:
array([[41, 39, 23, 32,  2,  7],
       [34,  7, 23, 47,  1, 29],
       [31, 28, 23, 30, 21,  1],
       [ 2,  2, 40,  4, 30,  4],
       [ 8,  6, 49, 34, 26,  1]])

In [52]: arr[:, np.argmax(arr.max(axis=0))]
Out[52]: array([23, 23, 23, 40, 49])
```

Comment: Спасибо "@MaxU !